# Trying to send balance to owner of contract

Tags: solidity, remix

Code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract init {
        address owner;
        function init()
        {
            owner = msg.sender;
        }

        function send() public payable{
            owner.transfer(msg.value);

        }  
}
```

[image: attached is the image of code and the console]

Comment: It doesn't look like you asked a question here. Are you running into some issue?

Comment: yes. it is not transferring the balance to owner

Comment: i want to transfer the ether balance which is (100 Ether by default in remix) to the owner when the sender execute send function.

Comment: Check my answer. The user needs to select how much Ether they will send. The transaction will not automatically choose an Ether amount, nor can you automatically have a contract transfer the entire balance of a user. The user must explicitly include how much they want to send as a part of the transaction's parameters. If you want to automate the transfer of the full balance of the user, you may be able to use a front end ux with web3.js to automatically figure out the total balance of the user, and input that as a part of the transaction to be signed.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer. IT cleared my doubt. Actually i have implemented it using web3 using the same process which you told. i just wanted to make a contract which can do so by its own end without using web3 at the back end

Comment: Think about how dangerous it would be if a contract could do that. I could trick you to call my function, and steal all your Ether. Actions like this should be, and are, explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a better look at the screenshot you provided, you are not sending any value in your transaction, therefore nothing happens...

You need to make sure to set the `value` option when initiating the `send` transaction.

It should look like this:
[image: Image of a transaction while sending value]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer the entire balance of the contract to the owner of the contract, then you should replace `msg.value` with `address(this).balance`.

If the balance of the contract prior to calling function `send` is 0, then it will indeed transfer the entire balance of the contract to the owner of the contract.

Otherwise, you are transferring to the owner of the contract the exact amount of ether that the caller of function `send` has just transferred to the contract.